# "I don't believe you" vs. "I don't believe in you"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Is it correct to use the word "in"? We say, "I have faith in me". In the same way, can we say "I don't believe in you"?

Comment: "I don't believe you." can mean either I think you're not telling the truth or that your behavior is outrageous.  "I don't believe *in* you." means that I don't have faith in you.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of *you* how about you say *ghosts*?

> I don't believe ghosts.

This means that when ghosts tell you things, you tend to think they're lying.

There is another meaning that is conveyed when the phrase is said in an exasperated or angry tone, which is that you are surprised and angered/exasperated by the behaviour of ghosts.

> I don't believe in ghosts.

This means you do not believe in the existence of ghosts.

All of these meanings are applicable to the sentence when *you* is used.

However, "I don't believe in you" also means "I have no faith in you". Context should provide the required clues as to which meaning is relevant.

Comment: "I have no faith in you" here meaning "I have no confidence in you". It is said that Abraham Lincoln was once asked "Do you believe in God?" and he replied, "The question is, Does God believe in me?" (I have no idea if Lincoln really said it or if the story is apocryphal.) Note the shift in meaning from "affirm the existence of" to "have confidence in".